# Apps not showing metrics under App Analytics on App Store Connect

Tags: app-store-connect

On Jan 2, 2024 I uploaded and got released 13 new apps. The problem I'm having is that only one of the new apps is showing data under analytics the other 12 show nothing. They are all a similar series of apps with pretty much the same search criteria as many of my apps, 42 total. All of the other apps show plenty of analytic data.

I've done searches and the apps do show up in the search.

I understand there's no limit to the number of apps you can have so, I'm a bit confused.

Does anybody know if there is there a way to have Apple look and see if I've done something wrong that's causing the problem?

Does anybody else run into something like this?